# My react test are not working because of api call

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm writing test for a component that call's an api to collect data. Problem is that my view in test renders before collecting data from api and all fields in HTML parts are empty.

my component view

```
export default class ExampleView extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.GetData();
  }
  GetData = () => {
    //Call api and get data set in local variable
 };
```

My testCase

```
describe('<ExampleView />', () => {

  let res;
  beforeEach(() => {
    res = sinon.spy(RailsConnection.prototype, 'get');
    mock.onAny().reply(200, object);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    res.restore();
  });

  it('renders without errors  ', () => {
    html = mount(<ExampleView/>);
    console.log(html.html());
  });
};
```

my html is without data

Comment: are you setting in state or on an instance? The initial pass will render empty if there is an async query happening

Comment: It's on instance

Comment: need to see the rest of your component code. And I'd recommend react-testing-library

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your API call in a [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) method to make sure that the data is returned before the component completes its first render.  You're also not binding your method correctly:

```
export default class ExampleView extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }
  getData = () => {
    //Call api and get data set in local variable
  };

  componentDidMount() {
     this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    return <div/>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Let me give it a try

Comment: Please post the real code you are using for your component.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with

```
it('renders without errors  ', () => {
    html = mount(<ExampleView/>);
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve))
    html.update()
    console.log(html.html());
  });
```